# Searching Ip Addresses in Lotus Notes mail client

Tags: regex, search, lotus-notes

I would like to search any IP Addresses that would exist in the body of mails that is in my inbox on Lotus notes.
I am assuming some regular expression with wildcards should be used when searching.

Thanx in advance for any assistance.

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: Well, i tried "*.*.*.*", "*.*", "^(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])$" with no results

Comment: Show your code, not just the regex.

Comment: @ Richard Schwartz I am using the search box in lotus notes client, so not to sure what code, I am very new to Lotus and not sure if this is achievable?

Comment: In that case, I need to tell you that stackoverflow is for programming questions, not for questions about how to use features of programs like Lotus Notes. Your question belongs on SuperUser.com.  However, I can tell you that Lotus Notes has two built-in search features, only the full text search" feature can search the body, and the full text search feature will not be helpful for finding IP addresses.

Comment: This question is actually **not "off-topic"** because it can be solved only by developing some code like an agent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least two^H^H^Hthree regexp-like engines in Lotus Notes, and none of them is even close to as powerful as common [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap09.html) tools. Specifically, you cannot use constructs like `[0-9]{1,3}` (for 1-3 digits) in any of them.

- The LotusScript [like](http://www-12.lotus.com/ldd/doc/domino_notes/rnext/help6_designer.nsf/f4b82fbb75e942a6852566ac0037f284/3090ec8617414f1b85256c54004c3b1b?OpenDocument) operator: Operates on strings in LotusScript. Less powerful than @Matches, for example you cannot express something like *any number of Bs*.
- The Formula language [@Matches](http://www-12.lotus.com/ldd/doc/domino_notes/rnext/help6_designer.nsf/f4b82fbb75e942a6852566ac0037f284/e2e7eda26ed4f01e85256c54004c0a22?OpenDocument) function: Slightly more powerful, for example you have disjunction and conjunctions to play with.
- The Formula language [@Like](http://www-12.lotus.com/ldd/doc/domino_notes/rnext/help6_designer.nsf/f4b82fbb75e942a6852566ac0037f284/bbcf67af7dfaa4cf85256c54004c0750?OpenDocument) function. The simplest of them all - essentially string matching with wildcards for single and multiple characters.

To solve your specific problem (assuming you want a view of all documents where the body contains an ip address), I'd use `@Match` and write a pattern that matches `+{0-9}{0-9}.+{0-9}{0-9}.+{0-9}{0-9}.+{0-9}{0-9}` - it's a relaxation of the requirement to match four groups of digits separated by dots. This will match ip addresses, but also sequences like `12345.12151315.141241.1421`.

Answer (score 1):

There is no "out of the box" regular expressions search included in Lotus Notes Client. The Notes full text search doesn't support searches for e.g. IP addresses, unfortunately.

You would have to write an agent.

The easiest would be an Java agent which reads the **text only part** of item `Body` of every (selected) document as a String and tests it for IP addresses using `java.util.regex.Matcher`. Look at Google for "regex IP address java" and you'll find a lot of good example code.

You could also write an LotusScript agent. Here is an [example](http://www.bleedyellow.com/blogs/texasswede/entry/regular_expressions_in_notes_lotusscript?lang=en) to start with.

*@Like*, *@Matches* and operator *like* don't allow you to find exactly IP addresses so why not use regex as it's possible.